# QGIS Atlas point for each column attribute

Tags: point, fields-attributes, qgis-atlas

I want to automate the export of maps of a point layer automatically for each of the columns of the attribute table. It's possible?

| SP_A1 | _Defo_m | _Deco_m | _Int_t1 | _Int_T2 | _Int_T3 | _Int_T4 | _Int_T5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E.globulus | 27,5 | 0 | 0 | 1,52 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| E.globulus | 38,1 | 0 | 0 | 1,52 | 1,3 | 3 | 0 |
| E.globulus | 43,1 | 0 | 0 | 2,13 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| P.radiata | 24,4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1,22 | 0 |
| E.globulus | 31 | 0 | 0 | 1,29 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I share a map that how must be the style. I´d like to export the same maps for all columns.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide examples of how your maps would/should differ?

Comment: Hi Erik,  I modified the post with 2 new images.

Comment: So you want different symbologies for the same layer?

Comment: Exactly, the style is always the same, but ara serveral variables, one for each column of table of attribute

Comment: No, the style/symbology is not the same, since you want to categorize the data using different attributes. You probably have to duplicate the layer as often as needed, then style it accordingly and finally create an atlas using your duplicate layers.

Comment: Sorry Erik for the confusion. 
I need to automatically export the map that is displayed for each of the columns. Each column represents the number of trees (0-24) that are affected by a pest. There are more than 40 different plagues, so I would like to export it automatically, as if it were an atlas, but instead of taking a map for each feature, take a map for each column.